Most up to date explanation explaining the stability of high spin multiplicity (multiplicity=$2S+1$) states?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hund%27s_rules:

"However, accurate quantum-mechanical calculations (starting in the 1970s)... singly occupied orbitals are less effectively screened or shielded from the nucleus, so that such orbitals contract and electron–nucleus attraction energy becomes greater in magnitude (or decreases algebraically)."

Where do I find these calculations, papers, or data?

I suspect it refers to Hartree-Fock self consistent field calculations for the wavefunctions of atoms. These only became possible in the 1970s as computer power increased. By the time I started doing them in the early 1980s they were fairly routine. However I don't think we can answer your question as only the person who wrote that part of the article knows what they meant.

You can perform these calculations using the "exact diagonalization" method, but you need a computer for two main reasons: (1) the size of the matrix to be diagonalized increases exponentially with the number of single-particle orbitals considered; (2) to perform the radial integrations (which are otherwise treated as free parameters call the "Slater-Condon" parameters). An early code from the 70s that you might want to investigate is Cowan's Code: https://www.mdpi.com/2218-2004/7/3/64

(According to the linked article, that code alone has been cited in more than 5000 papers... So, it will be hard to "find" them all...)
